# How to generate div with checkbox from database in Laravel

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, laravel-8

I have 3 tables user can be edited by the user 
first table: cars 
second table: locations
third table: price,
In addCars.blade.php
, I want to add a price based on location  [the locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S83WS.png)
when I check the checkbox a new price div generate with a new id and inputs id

the car hasMany price based on each location in the database

```
@foreach ($locations as $locations)

<div class="container-fluid"  id="div1">
<div class="fade-in">
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header"> pricing {{ $locations->name }}</div>
<div class="card-body">                      
      <div class="body">

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">car number</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="carnumber" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="car number">
        </div>   
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">price</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="price" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="price">
        </div>  
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">min day</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="minday" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="min day">
        </div>  
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">sale price</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="saleprice" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="sale price">
        </div>  
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">min day stay</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mindaystay" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="min day stay">
        </div>  
        

</div>
</div>
</div>

<button type="submit" onclick="location.href='/cars'" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

[the price div that I want to create for each new location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbbLK.png)

Comment: Unrelated: you seem to have multiple elements with the same `id` attribute - which is invalid. Make sure you use unique `id`s

Comment: this seems right for me, whats wrong?

Comment: How are you fetching the locations data ?